# State of Native Support for Scheme and Common Lisp on Apple Silicon?

Tags: development, emacs, apple-silicon

I tinker on and off with Scheme (usually [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/) rather than Racket), and with Common Lisp. Essentially all of this is from the command line and through [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [Geiser](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) and [SLIME](https://slime.common-lisp.dev/).

Native support for Apple Silicon would be preferable, but I can use X86 emulation if that is the only way.

What is the current state of Scheme compilers and interpreters on Apple Silicon, and what is the current state of Common Lisp compilers on Apple Silicon?

I am particularly interested in: [Chez Scheme](https://github.com/cisco/chezscheme), [Guile 3.0](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [SBCL](https://www.sbcl.org/), [CCL](https://ccl.clozure.com/) and [CLISP](https://www.gnu.org/software/clisp/).

I did google each individual interpreter/compile + "Apple silicon" and "Apple M1" (and M2), and did visit the website of most of them, but got little or no information, and occasionally conflicting information, on most of them.

I intend to use this on an M2 Macbook Air.

Answer (score 2):

I would just check with the folks that make each of the apps you want to use.

For example, here is a discussion of apple silicon for Chez Scheme, started in 2020: https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/issues/544

And SBCL lists both amd64 and arm64, so that's good to go.

Clisp is ancient... web page shows 2010, but Homebrew lists support for apple silicon: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/clisp

Comment: Based on your answer, I tried installing with homebrew and had it going 2 minutes later (on M2 chip).

Comment: Glad to hear it; we were lucky. Have fun!